# Restricting a div to be displayed during page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a template where a huge amount of data is loading. In that template 5-6 div's are also present, each div having its own purpose. Initially all the div's are made as **display:none**. On click of respective buttons the div class would be toggled(either **display:none** or **display:''**).  When the template is loading getting all data from server side, its taking some time, in the mean time all the div's(which are display:none) is getting displayed. That means the **display:none** property is not working. When the page loads completely with all the data then only **display:none** works, and the div's became invisible, and works correcting(toggling) afterwards. How can i restrict the display of div's initially.

**Code:**

```
<div class="display_none" id="zip_search">
    <label>Enter Area Code</label>
    <input type="text" class="input-medium" id="search_zip" maxlength="5">
</div>

<a class="btn btn-primary" id="area_link">Show Area</a>

$("#area_link").click(function () {
    $("#zip_search").toggleClass("display_none");
});


.display_none{
    display:none;
}
```

After the page has been loaded completely, div's became invisible, and also the toggleClass() is working fine after that.

Comment: Check the css you included is in the `head section` if it is,then I don't think that this will create problem while page loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your jQuery fired on document ready?
Like this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#area_link").click(function () {
        $("#zip_search").toggleClass("display_none");
    });
});
```

otherwise the toggleClass function will execute while the page (html + css) isn't fully loaded.

Comment: Yes the jQuery is fired inside document ready. The toggleClass() is working fine after is page is loaded completely. But I guess the css is not loading until the page is not loaded completely.

Comment: The HTML is downloaded first. The browser starts reading the html from the top, and starts fetching all CSS and JavaScript files referenced in the HEAD section. The page will not be painted (shown) until all the CSS and JavaScript files in the HEAD have been downloaded and evaluated. So that can't be the problem. Do you have a live example of you code somewhere?

Comment: So silly..(headbang). Got the issue and fixed it. I have written all the css classes down to the page, now moved to the head of the page and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

What about using inline-css for the div? (`style="display:none;"`) Sure it is not an very nice solution, but it could do the trick!

Comment: ohh.. I see.. you mean to say I should remove the class and use inline css. Then in javascript I will use addAttr() and removeAttr() as a alternate to toggleClass().

Comment: You could also pass the class to the element. But from the rendering order it should first apply the inline-css. Not tested, but just try it out.